# How can I write the following query in an executable way in SQL Server Express 2008

Tags: sql-server, xbase

```
select doc_no,date,acc_no,amount,
if xvar=1
(select acc_head from my_crem c where c.acc_no=o.acc_no) as acc_head
else
(select acc_head from my_debm c where c.acc_no=o.acc_no) as acc_head
from my_ordm o;
```

In the above query, `xvar` is not a column name. It's a local variable name. Then how can I write the above query?

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
    o.doc_no,
    o.date,
    o.acc_no,
    o.amount, 
    CASE 
         WHEN @xvar = 1 THEN c.acc_head 
         ELSE d.acc_head
    END as acc_head
from 
    my_ordm o
    left join my_crem c on c.acc_no = o.acc_no   
    left join my_debm d on d.acc_no = o.acc_no;
```

Comment: here first acc_head is from my_crem table and second from my_debm table...can u help for this one...

Comment: thr xvar is not a column name it's a local variable ...thn how can i do that one ...xvar have 2 value either 1 or 2....plz help me

Comment: Put @xvar instead of xvar, and it should be fine. The order of the join is irrelevant in this context, just make sure the CASE is correct, so when @xvar = 1 you're getting acc_head from my_crem instead of my_debm.

Comment: srry...now aLSO IT DOES'T WRKS....must declare the scalar variable like that one error comess....

Comment: @Ajeesh Kumar S: So what is wrong then? You clarified in your question that `xvar` is a variable. Now the script is using the variable `@xvar`. It is a correct solution to your present question. Otherwise your question is missing important details.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    doc_no,
    date,
    acc_no,
    amount,
    Case @xvar 
           WHEN 1 Then (select acc_head from my_crem c where c.acc_no = o.acc_no)
           ELSE (select acc_head from my_debm c where c.acc_no = o.acc_no)
    END AS acc_head 
from my_ordm o;
```

Comment: but xvar is not a column name..it is private variable...thn how can i solve this one...plz help me

Comment: I think you forget to put '@' before your variable name 
I have edited the code and it should work now